# CondorHT - Six idle Procs all creating snapshots continuously. Whats wrong?

Tags: condor

I inherited a CondorHT cluster that crunches cloud metrics.
One master controller node. Six worker nodes.
The cluster was running perfectly for months then suddenly it breaks.
The cluster normally takes 1 to 2 hrs to complete but now never completes and is shut down/cut off by a daily cron shutdown at midnight.

The CollectorLog on the master node updates with messages indicating some activity is occuring. The messages arrive about one every 20 seconds.

The ProcLog on the master node and worker nodes updates with messages about one every 20 seconds. "no methods have determined process xxxx to be in a monitored family....taking a snapshot...snapshot complete."

The condor_status on the master node shows all processes as IDLE.

How can I debug this?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. The way HTCondor works is that it schedules job on machines.  Sounds like the jobs are idle.  Or, maybe there aren't any jobs.  So, let's start there.  If you run condor_q, or maybe condor_q -all, depending on the version of condor, what does that say about the jobs?

Comment: Thanks for getting back with me Greg.  Here is the info you asked for.

Comment: CondorHT version 8.3.8

condor_q

master node
========================
-- Schedd: ip-1-2-3-0.ab-cde-efg-h.compute.internal : <1.2.3.0:19256>
ID   OWNER    SUBMITTED     RUN_TIME   ST   PRI   SIZE   CMD

0 jobs; 0 completed, 0 removed, 0 idle, 0 running, 0 held, 0 suspended

Comment: I believe I fixed the problem.  I added logging that broke the scheduler. After I took the logging out it works.  Sorry for the false alarm.